# Как избавиться от от пустого пространства между внешним и внутренним блоками?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Google Chrome (возможно и другие браузеры тоже) при рендеринге [такой разметки](https://jsfiddle.net/amdk0zcp/) оставляет заметную незаполненную полосу в 1px между внешним блоком с рамкой и внутренним блоком с картинкой в качестве фона. Подскажите, как от неё избавиться?
[image: Белая полоса между внутренним и внешним блоками]

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.picture{
    flex: 0 0 225px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/20/2e/2f/202e2fecd102336639761fb07dc600bc.jpg');
}

.text{
  margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="picture"></div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum iure, aliquam amet magni voluptate quo nulla odio minima blanditiis numquam consectetur adipisci pariatur exercitationem dolorem in ab repellat quibusdam deserunt!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, самый очевидный способ - отказаться от `border` и использовать `box-shadow`:

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}

.picture{
    flex: 0 0 225px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/20/2e/2f/202e2fecd102336639761fb07dc600bc.jpg');
}

.text{
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="picture"></div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum iure, aliquam amet magni voluptate quo nulla odio minima blanditiis numquam consectetur adipisci pariatur exercitationem dolorem in ab repellat quibusdam deserunt!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что вариант решения проблемы высказанный мной в соседней ветке комментариев: "имитировать границу внешнего блока границами внутренних блоков"  - чуть оптимальнее с точки зрения производительности. Хотя ваш вариант с точки зрения количества кода явно лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить для всего `body` margin 0

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.picture{
    flex: 0 0 225px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/20/2e/2f/202e2fecd102336639761fb07dc600bc.jpg');
}

.text{
  margin: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Не помогло. Тонкая пустая полоска в 1px всё равно осталась и появляется то снизу то сверху с изменением масштаба страницы.

Comment: Я понял о чём ты, это походу баги, у меня такое на масштабе 250% вылазит, на других всё норм, но это даже не 1px, вообще не заметная штука

Comment: Я добавил скриншот в вопрос для лучшей иллюстрации проблемы. Возможно это из за того что у меня на Windows стоит масштабирование 125%.

Comment: Я благодаря скрину и увидел)
Я сейчас даже полностью по другому код переписал, при масштабировании точно так же, никуда оно не ушло

Comment: Проблема обходится удалением border у внешнего блока и задания верхней, нижней и левой границы у левого внутреннего блока; и верхней, нижней и правой границы у правого внутреннего блока. Но это уже какой то костыль, честно говоря.

Comment: та не костыль, просто много лишнего кода выходит, ну, буду знать как это решить если кого то из заказчиков будет такое волновать)